# Changing basis vectors should change coordinates in the space?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading about computer graphics from [here](http://www.amazon.in/Math-Primer-Graphics-Development-Edition/dp/1568817231). Here is one excerpt:

> We briefly mention here two examples, both from the world of graphics.
>
> Imagine we want to animate a squishing or stretching motion of our robot model.
>   To do so, we would modify the coordinate space used to interpret the coordinates of our vertices.
>   We would animate the basis vectors of the robot's object space, probably in ways that caused them to have different lengths from one another or to cease to be perpendicular.
>
> As we squish or stretch the object-space vectors, the object-space coordinates of the vertices remain constant, but the resulting camera-space coordinates change, producing the desired animation.
>
> <sub>— [original paragraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26F3Y.png)</sub>

From what I understand, he is saying that instead of taking something like $\{ [1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1] \}$, probably take something like $\{[1,0,0], [0,.25,0], [0,0,1]\}$ as basis vectors, for example.

I didn't get this part:

> As we squish or stretch the object-space vectors, **the object-space coordinates of the vertices remain constant**, but the resulting camera-space coordinates change, producing the desired animation.

If we change the basis vectors of object space, shouldn't the coordinates change in the object space as well?

Consider this case where initially the bases vectors are $i$ and $j$. A random point in this cases can be represented by vector $(2i,2j)$.

If however I change the bases vectors to $i' = 0.5i$ and $j' = j$, new vector representation will be $(4i',2j')$.

Isn't this a change in the coordinates in the object space?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The object space coordinates should change if you want the camera space coordinates to remain the same.

But imagine what happens if you change the transformation from object to camera space as described in the quote. You get the desired effect. In practice this means multiplying a matrix that isn't the identity matrix with the object space coordinates.